# GEOTOOLS - Failing to generate jar

Tags: geotools

I am trying to generate a jar file for my geotools application. However, when I try to run the jar file, I get the following error:

[image]

Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.geotools.tutorial</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>15.1</geotools.version>
    <geotools.version>17-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-render</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <source>1.8</source>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
                          <!-- would with the assembly plugin                                       -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <manifestEntries>
                                  <Main-Class>org.geotools.tutorial.ImageLab</Main-Class>
                              </manifestEntries>
                          </transformer>
                          <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Does it work in your IDE? Which of the two versions are you building with? Have you [installed the imageIO package](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/build/install/jdk.html)? Did you follow the steps in the [FAQ about the shade plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app)?

Comment: yes, it works on my IDE. I followed the steps about the shade plugin. Do I have to install the imageIO package if it compiles fine on my IDE? I am using Eclipse and Windows 7 x64, haven't found imageIO for 32 bits. The version linked on geotools documentation doesn't work on my operating system, it tells me that I don't have the JDK installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following attributes to my pom file:

```
<manifestEntries>
<Main-Class>com.br.iacit.tutorialdoJar.ImageLab</Main-Class>
<Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
<Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
<Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
<Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
<Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
<Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
</manifestEntries>
```